# Why is the root password required to install most applications?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, permissions

Most applications require the root password to be installed.

Yet, when you run them, they seem to be running under a regular user.

Why is the root password required upon installation if the application has no root privileges?

Comment: By restricting to root ability to make changes to where apps get installed into it prevents non root from breaking things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu any changes to parts of the filesystem that are owned exclusively by root (such as installing, upgrading and uninstalling software from the default Ubuntu repositories) must be made by a user who has root privileges to prevent ordinary users from making changes to the parts of the filesystem that are owned exclusively by root.

Run commands that require root privileges by prefacing the command with `sudo`. Then you will be asked to authenticate the command by typing your user password. The authentication automatically expires after a short time, so if you walk away from the terminal after running commands as root using `sudo`, you will not be leaving a root terminal open indefinitely.

> Does that mean that at the point of installation I'm giving the application absolute permissions, even if the application doesn't run as root in the end?

When you install software using apt, you must run the command as root in order to give apt permission to install the package and any dependencies required by the package. A package that is installed by apt as root receives permission to access any dependency packages that it requires to work properly, even when the application is run by a normal user.

This policy enables Ubuntu to be a secure operating system.

From [Ubuntu Documentation Root sudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

> In Linux (and Unix in general), there is a SuperUser named root. The Windows equivalent of root is the Administrators group. The SuperUser can do anything and everything, and thus doing daily work as the SuperUser can be dangerous. You could type a command incorrectly and destroy the system. Ideally, you run as a user that has only the privileges needed for the task at hand. In some cases, this is necessarily root, but most of the time it is a regular user.

Comment: Does that mean that at the point of installation I'm giving the application absolute permissions, even if the application doesn't run as root in the end?

Comment: This is a very good question, so I'm going to edit it into my answer. When you install software using apt, you must run the command as root in order to give apt permission to install the package and any dependencies required by the package.

Comment: So I'm essentially giving the root permissions to the `apt` package manager not the application itself right? And then `apt` allows the application to use only specific dependencies not everything on the system.

Comment: Ubuntu is based on Debian and most Ubuntu software packages use the .deb package format. .deb packages contain information about their required dependencies that apt can read, so that apt or gdebi can automatically resolve all required dependencies when a .deb package is being installed.